# JTable : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, exception, jtable

I am trying to get the value of a row of a JTable in Java, the rows' values 
are from a database:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
                   {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) 
                        {

                    //eTime.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                   // eName.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
                   // eValue.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
                   // cName.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
                   // cModel.setText(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
                            try{
                   System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
                            }catch(Exception g)
                    { System.out.println(g);

                    }}
                    });
```

when I press on a row of that table I get the following exception: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Print out the value of `table.getSelectedRow()`

Comment: `ListSelectionListener` will trigger to updates, one for a deselection and one for selection. Make sure you are only checking when the selection is set